# Splitting "-" in a string to column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with strings like below:

string = ------AJBHGC-----

I want to split the above string to 2 columns

string1 = ------ # all dashes before alphabets to one

string2 = AJBHGC----- # rest including dashes

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("----ATCGDVC---", 
"--CHBD----CHD--", "--CVGDVC"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

When I try to split it groups all the dashes together and letters together. Can anyone help

output should look like this:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("----ATCGDVC---", 
"--CHBD----CHD--", "--CVGDVC"), class = "factor"), string1 = c("----", 
"--", "--"), string2 = c("ATCGDVC---", "CVGDVC", "CHBD----CHD--"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT - Other way round. Dashes at the end ("$" doesn't work)

```
OUTPUT <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("----ATCGDVC---", "--CHBD----CHD--", "--CVGDVC"), class = "factor"), string1 = c("----ATCGDVC", "--CVGDVC", "--CHBD----CHD"), string2 = c("---", "", "--")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** **extract** An option would be `extract` to capture one or more characters (`+`) that are a `-` from the start of the string (`^`) by capturing it as a group inside the brackets (`(...)`) followed by other characters (`.*`) as the second set of capture group

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   extract(V1, into = c("string1", "string2"), "^(-+)(.*)", remove = FALSE)
#                V1 string1       string2
#1  ----ATCGDVC---    ----    ATCGDVC---
#2        --CVGDVC      --        CVGDVC
#3 --CHBD----CHD--      -- CHBD----CHD--
```

**2)** **separate** - Or using `separate` with a regex lookaround

```
df1 %>% 
     separate(V1, into = c("string1", "string2"), "(?<=-)(?!-)",
               extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)
#               V1 string1       string2
#1  ----ATCGDVC---    ----    ATCGDVC---
#2        --CVGDVC      --        CVGDVC
#3 --CHBD----CHD--      -- CHBD----CHD--
```

---No package zone/area from below

**3)**  **regmatches/regexpr/trimws** - `base R` method.  Here, we make use of `regmatches/regexpr` to extract the prefix characters that are `-` and `trimws` to remove the characters that are `-` at the prefix.

```
df1[c("string1", "string2")] <-  list(regmatches(df1$V1, 
           regexpr("^-+", df1$V1)), trimws(df1$V1, "left", "-"))

df1
#               V1 string1       string2
#1  ----ATCGDVC---    ----    ATCGDVC---
#2        --CVGDVC      --        CVGDVC
#3 --CHBD----CHD--      -- CHBD----CHD--
```

**4)** **strcapture** - or another `base R` option is `strcapture`

```
cbind(df1, strcapture("^(-+)(.*)", df1$V1, 
        list(string1 = character(0), string2 = character(0))))

#               V1 string1       string2
#1  ----ATCGDVC---    ----    ATCGDVC---
#2        --CVGDVC      --        CVGDVC
#3 --CHBD----CHD--      -- CHBD----CHD--
```

Comment: Hello @akrun, I want to extract dashes the same way from the end. The "$" instead of "^" doesn't work. Can you please suggest a way? Thanks

Comment: @user11352627  In that case use `"(.*)(-+)$"` in `str_capture`

Comment: Thank you Akron, But that just gives the last "-" in string2 (just 1), It doesn't return all at the end.

Comment: @user11352627. Can you please update your post with the expected output

Comment: @user11352627. Try `df1 %>% extract(V1, into = c("string1", "string2"), "(.*[A-Z])(-*)$", remove = FALSE)`

Answer (score 5):

**1) sub** Replace the first non-minus and everything after it with the empty string to form `string1`.  Then remove the leading minuses to form `string2`.  Assuming `dd` is the name of your data frame we have the following.  No packages are used.

```
transform(dd, string1 = sub("[^-].*", "", V1), string2 = sub("^-*", "", V1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
               V1 string1       string2
1  ----ATCGDVC---    ----    ATCGDVC---
2        --CVGDVC      --        CVGDVC
3 --CHBD----CHD--      -- CHBD----CHD--
```

The `stringsAsFactors` argument is optional.  It ensures that the result is character.  If it is omitted then `string1` and `string2` will be factor.

**2) read.table** Another possibility is to insert a special character such as comma after the leading minuses and then use `read.table`.  Again, no packages are used.

```
dd2 <- read.table(text = sub("^(-*)", "\\1,", dd$V1), 
  sep = ",", as.is = TRUE, col.names = c("string1", "string2"))
cbind(dd, dd2)
```

**3) trimws** If you don't really need `string1` and you are using R 3.6 or later then `trimws` could be used.  Again, no packages are used.

```
transform(dd, string2 = trimws(V1, "left", "-"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
               V1       string2
1  ----ATCGDVC---    ATCGDVC---
2        --CVGDVC        CVGDVC
3 --CHBD----CHD-- CHBD----CHD--
```

Again, the `stringsAsFactors` argument is optional.

Comment: Thank you so much @Grothendieck!

Comment: Use this: `transform(dd, string1 = sub("[^-].*", "", V1), 
              string2 = gsub("^-*|-*$", "", V1),
              string3 = sub(".*[^-]", "", V1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you, it worked @Grothendieck. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Arguably more complicated than it should be but another `base` solution:

```
splits<-strsplit(gsub("(-(?=[A-Z]{4,}))([A-Z]+)","\\1 \\2",df$V1,
              perl=TRUE),
          "\\s(?<=)",perl=T)
 df$string_1 <- sapply(splits,"[[",1)
 df$string_2 <- sapply(splits, "[[", 2)
 df
               V1 string_1      string_2
1  ----ATCGDVC---     ----    ATCGDVC---
2        --CVGDVC       --        CVGDVC
3 --CHBD----CHD--       -- CHBD----CHD--
```

**EDIT**:
To avoid unnecessary double `sapply`, `rbind`ing might be more efficient:

```
data.frame(V1=df[,-c(2,3)],do.call(rbind,splits))#c(2,3) because I used the same df as above
               V1   X1            X2
1  ----ATCGDVC--- ----    ATCGDVC---
2        --CVGDVC   --        CVGDVC
3 --CHBD----CHD--   -- CHBD----CHD--
```

One can then proceed with `rename`ing the data set as desired.